# Lack of available module names on NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I would like to start publishing modules to NPM but I am concerned about the dwindling amount of sane module names within the public namespace.

**Is it possible to create a public NPM module that namespaces all of my module names?**

It would be nice to have a system such as github that places your repository names under your own username.

Comment: that's a tragic mistake from npm creators. I use mpm.* as a namespace. And the answer to your question is NO.

Comment: Was there a documented reason behind the way that works?  The minute I started using NPM, I wondered about naming problems.

Comment: @zero298: [Yes.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22057546/201952)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solving npm’s hard problem: naming packages.**

Naming things just got a little bit easier for npm users with the introduction of scopes. npm has rolled out scopes as part of the release of private modules last week, but scopes can be used for public packages, too.

**What are scopes?**

Scopes are like namespaces for npm packages. Each npm user has their own scope.

```
@username/project-name
```

This means that we don’t have to worry about someone else taking our package name. We can add packages in our scope.

Start using scope today.

For more details follow this [link](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/116936804365/solving-npms-hard-problem-naming-packages)

Answer (score 2):

npm now supports [scopes](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope), which is a change from the previous policy:

---

<s>No, by design.  The public npm registry does not support namespacing and probably never will.</s>

From [the FAQ](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-faq.html#Why-no-namespaces):

> ### Why no namespaces?
>
> Please see this discussion: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/798
>
> tl;dr - It doesn't actually make things better, and can make them worse.
>
> If you want to namespace your own packages, you may: simply use the `-` character to separate the names. npm is a mostly anarchic system. There is not sufficient need to impose namespace rules on everyone.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

However, you can use github itself to host your packages instead of npm registry. Since github has namespaces, this could solve the issue.